# MYSQL multiple query in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

See I have the following mysql code----

```
" SELECT * FROM members WHERE login_name='" . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN'] . "' "
```

But I want to include other login names too. For example this user's friends login name to show the posts of them also.

Comment: That query has nothing to do with posts. Nor does it have anything to do with friends... How do we know who is friends with who?

Comment: That is other script that generates friends login name in a session array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..... WHERE login_name IN ('a', 'b', 'c')